# how do I change color of hamburger icon?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am having trouble trying to change the color of a hamburger icon.

I cannot find which bit of code changes it. I want it to be white, but it shows as dark on small screens. Strangely, when I use the developer tool in Google Chrome on my PC and reduce the screen to trigger the hamburger menu, it is displayed in white, but not on actual small screens.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php include("includes/analytics.php");?>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<style>
body{
margin: 0px;
background-color: #759a79;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 12pt;
}
.topnav {
width: 100%;
max-width: 1200px;
background-color: #3c7743;
position: fixed;
z-index: 20;
top: 0;
}
.topnav a {
float: left;
display: block;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 17px;
}
.active {
background-color: #12671b;
color: white;
}
.topnav .icon {
display: none;
}
.dropdown {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}
.dropdown .dropbtn {
font-size: 17px;
border: none;
outline: none;
color: white;
padding: 14px 16px;
background-color: inherit;
font-family: inherit;
margin: 0;
}
.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: #f9f9f9;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: black;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
background-color: #666;
color: white;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: #ddd;
color: black;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
display: block;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 610px) {
.content2 {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
width: 30%;
background-color: #ffffff;
padding: 10px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 610px) {
.content2 {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: left;
width: 90%;
background-color: #ffffff;
padding: 10px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
.topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
display: none;
}
.topnav a.icon {
float: right;
display: block;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
.topnav.responsive .icon {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
.topnav.responsive a {
float: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;
}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
display: block;
width: 100%;
text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<?php
if($page=="1"){
echo ' <a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a>';
}
else{
echo ' <a href="index.php">Home</a>';
}
if($page=="2"){
echo ' <a href="dog-kennels.php" class="active">Dogs</a>';
}
else{
echo ' <a href="dog-kennels.php">Dogs</a>';
}
if($page=="3"){
echo ' <a href="cattery.php" class="active">Cats</a>';
}
else{
echo ' <a href="cattery.php">Cats</a>';
}
if($page=="4"){
echo ' <a href="dog-grooming.php" class="active">Dog Grooming</a>';
}
else{
echo ' <a href="dog-grooming.php">Dog Grooming</a>';
}
if($page=="5"){
echo ' <a href="find-drumbro-kennels.php" class="active">Location</a>';
}
else{
echo ' <a href="find-drumbro-kennels.php">Location</a>';
}echo ' <a href="tel:+441465460960">Telephone: 01465 460960</a>';
?>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px; color: #ffffff;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
<!-- the script below must be kept for nav bar -->
<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
if (x.className === "topnav") {
x.className += " responsive";
} else {
x.className = "topnav";
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am demented with this. I have tried adding

```
color: #FFFFFF;
```

to many parts of the navigation CSS code but it doesn't make any difference.

I have also tried adding

```
background-color: #FFFFFF;
```

to the various parts of the icon CSS but all that does is change the background area of the icon to white, which is not what I want

I also tried adding:

```
.icon{
color:#FFFFFF !important;
}
```

and

```
.icon{
background-color:#FFFFFF !important;
}
```

and:

```
 .icon .icon,
    .icon .icon-inner::before,
    .icon .icon-inner::after {
        background-color: white;
    }
```

but they don't work either.

I have searched on this site and all over with Google but cannot find a solution. I am sure there will be a previous question and answer about this but I cannot find it, so I apologise in advance if this is a duplicate.

Many thanks if anyone can help.

Tog
Edited Update:

New simplified code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>JS Bin</title>
<style>
body{
margin: 0px;
background-color: #759a79;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 12pt;
}
.icon {
color: #fff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px; color: #ffffff; text-decoration: none;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This displays white on my PC but black on my Samsung A5 Tablet and Samsung S9 phone

Comment: `color` should work - https://jsbin.com/mayizoz/edit?html,css,output. Maybe you have some other rule that overrides it?

Comment: @MoshFeu Yes, that does make sense. I will try adding the rest of my code line by line to see if I can find the culprit.

Comment: @MoshFeu I have updated with simplified code but still only white on PC and black on smaller screens

Comment: Can it be an issue with Samsung devices? Can they display your color darker than it is supposed to be? I suggest you try it on emulator or another brand of a device to eliminate that factor.

Comment: Strangely: if I use: <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px; color: #ffffff;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">Menu</a> It works, displaying "Menu" in white, so I shall use that instead of the hamburger :-)

Comment: I would recommend you to understand what's the problem, for you to learn :)

Comment: @MoshFeu I agree, but I cannot find the solution and the code is very minimal now.

Comment: @EvgeniiKlepilin I tried the emulator at: https://mobilemoxie.com/tools/mobile-page-test/ and it displays white correctly for many devices there including the Samsung S9, but not white not my Samsung S9. I am totally stumped, but using the text "Menu" workaround to get on with the website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search reveals that this seems to be a known bug: https://blog.futtta.be/2014/06/05/android-chrome-bug-when-styling-unicode-character/

This is from 2014... but maybe its still not fixed? Or your device needs updating?

Try using SVG or Icon Frameworks like https://fontawesome.com